# Solution to $\frac{dy}{dx} + \frac{y}{x}=e^{xy}\cos^{2}x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Good evening, may I know if my solution to the a/m problem is correct? Thank you.

Let $v=xy. $ Then $\dfrac{dv}{dx}= y+\dfrac{dy}{dx}x=xe^v\text{cos}^2{x}$

Hence, $\begin{align}\int e^{-v} dv = \int x\text{cos}^2x\end{align}dx \implies -e^{-xy}= \dfrac{x^2}{4}+\dfrac{x}{4} \text{sin}2x +\dfrac{1}{8}\text{cos}2x + C$

Comment: You can check directly from $y=-\ln(-(\frac{x^2}2+\frac x4\sin2x-\cos^2x+C))/x$.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that your procedure is correct. And bacause

$(\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x}{4} \sin 2x +\frac{1}{8}\cos 2x + C)'=x\cos^2x$, then

just make logarithmizing result and back substitution.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct.  You're welcome.

Check the final integral.

Wolfram Alpha couldn't solve it because it couldn't find the substitution $v=xy$.  I think your solution is correct except when you take the final integral $\int x\cos^2x \ \text{d}x$.

Comment: I have just checked my solution according to :http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dy%2Fdx+%2B+y%2Fx+%3D+%28e%5E%7Bxy%7D%29%28cosx%29%5E2

Comment: This answer to the question because if the mistake in the final integal is corrected as requested by Michael, the solution is obtained.